# GattLocalCharacteristic WriteRequested & ReadRequested events stop responding

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been developing BLE peripherals on UWP. I have to send a file to the mobile client. I divide the file into chunks on the server and ask the client for a WriteAsync request. The chunks are processed based on that WriteAsync request and send this processed response for the client's ReadAsync request. During this process, the client gets the chunk size, iterates to the size, sends the WriteAsync, and receives a response with the ReadAsync request.
The problem with is method is the WriteRequested & ReadRequested are not called after a few iterations.
Here is my code for UWP peripherals.

```
 private GattLocalCharacteristic fileListCharacteristic;
        private string exceptionString = "Exception: ";
        private Guid characteristicGuid = new Guid("xxxxxx");
        private Guid serviceGuid = new Guid("xxxxxx");
        private ResponseModel responseModel;
        private List<byte[]> data;  
        private byte[] chunkBuffer;  
// Create the GATT service provider
                GattServiceProviderResult serviceProviderResult = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(serviceGuid);
                if (serviceProviderResult.Error == BluetoothError.Success)
                {
                    GattServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceProviderResult.ServiceProvider;

                    // Create the GATT characteristic
                    GattLocalCharacteristicParameters characteristicParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters
                    {
                        CharacteristicProperties = GattCharacteristicProperties.Read | GattCharacteristicProperties.WriteWithoutResponse | GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify,
                        UserDescription = "File List Characteristic"
                    };
                    GattLocalCharacteristicResult characteristicResult = await serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(characteristicGuid, characteristicParameters);

                    if (characteristicResult.Error == BluetoothError.Success)
                    {
                        fileListCharacteristic = characteristicResult.Characteristic;
                        fileListCharacteristic.ReadRequested += FileListCharacteristicReadRequested;
                        fileListCharacteristic.WriteRequested += FileListCharacteristicWriteRequested;

                        // Start advertising the GATT service
                        serviceProvider.StartAdvertising();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error creating GATT characteristic: " + characteristicResult.Error);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error creating GATT service: " + serviceProviderResult.Error);
                }

 private async void FileListCharacteristicWriteRequested(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattWriteRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
            GattWriteRequest request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
            DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(request.Value);
            byte[] dataBytes = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
            reader.ReadBytes(dataBytes);
            string dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataBytes);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataString))
                return;
            responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(dataString);
            if (request.Option == GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse)
            {
                request.Respond();
            }           
            deferral.Complete();            
        }

 private async void FileListCharacteristicReadRequested(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattReadRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var deferral = args.GetDeferral();           
            string responseString = "OK";
            switch (responseModel.ResponseCode)
            {
                case 1:
                    List<FileInfoModel> fileList = await GetFileList();
                    responseString = SerializeFileList(fileList);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    byte[] fileBuffer = await GetFileContent(responseModel.ResponseMessage);
                    int bufferChunkSize = 508;
                    int ChunksCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)fileBuffer.Length / bufferChunkSize);
                    data = DivideByteArray(fileBuffer,bufferChunkSize);
                    ChunkInfo chunkInfo = new ChunkInfo()
                    {
                        FullPath = responseModel.ResponseMessage,
                        ChunkCount = ChunksCount
                    };
                    responseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chunkInfo);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    int currentChunk = responseModel.CurrentChunk;
                    chunkBuffer = data[currentChunk];
                    break;

                default:
                    responseString = "OK";
                    break;
            }
            IBuffer buffer = responseModel.ResponseCode == 3 ? chunkBuffer.AsBuffer() : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString).AsBuffer();
            GattReadRequest request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
            request?.RespondWithValue(buffer);
            deferral.Complete();

        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide Bluetooth logs to help us further check the problem for you? You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/busiotools/blob/master/bluetooth/tracing/readme.md) to collect the log.

Comment: I added SubscribedClientsChanged and AdvertisementStatusChanged events. I also change GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParametersadded and set IsConnectable to peripheralSupported & IsDiscoverable to true. I am getting a stable connection now. Also, I can iterate as per my need.